# SQL How to select distinct value from multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, field, distinct

In the database(of tutor profiles), each tutor can teach up to 3 subjects, hence I've created 3 fields--`Subject1`,`Subject2` & `Subject3`-- for each tutor. In my case, I would like to retrieve each specific subject within the 3 fields and add them to my combo box in my program for a criteria searching function.

Initially, I used the following code for 3 different fields :

```
Dim sqlSubjectComboBox As String = "SELECT DISTINCT [TutorSubject1] FROM tblTutor"
Dim cmdSubjectComboBox As New OleDbCommand(sqlSubjectComboBox, myConnection)
dr = cmdSubjectComboBox.ExecuteReader
While dr.Read()
    cbSubject.Items.Add(dr("TutorSubject1").ToString)
End While
```

However, I realised that this sql statement will create a logic error if a same subject is placed in different field for different tutor.

Ex : Tutor A has the subject 'Chemistry' on his field `Subject1`. While for Tutor B, he has the same subject 'Chemistry' on field `Subject2`. In the end, the combo box has two 'Chemistry'.

I had spent almost a day to figure this out but to avail, partly due to my subpar programming skill and lack of experience. Hopefully someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

Comment: You should have 3 rows, not 3 columns...

Comment: Ideally, you should have a separate table for subjects. Have a look at a union query to normalize your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the UNION operator to get the distinct list of subjects.

```
select TutorSubject1 FROM tblTutor where TutorSubject1 is not null
union
select TutorSubject2 FROM tblTutor where TutorSubject2 is not null
union
select TutorSubject3 FROM tblTutor where TutorSubject3 is not null
```

The important point here is that the UNION operator removes duplicates.